# From tibble to txt or excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, tidyr, tibble

Hi all: I am working with tibbles to summarise my data and now I have a problem. I need to send the data I have in a tibble to a partner in an excel or csv file format. The thing is that it requires the csv (or excel) file to be in a specific arrangement (no tidy data) so I was wondering if you can help me a little bit to, at least, have my tibble into a csv file in a way that would be easy to edit it in excel itself.

The tibble looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1,024 x 4
# Groups:   Treatment [16]
   Treatment    Pressure  mean   std
   <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 "I Control "    0.     97.2  1.03
 2 "I Control "    0.689  94.1  1.35
 3 "I Control "    1.38   90.9  2.01
 4 "I Control "    2.07   89.5  2.20
 5 "I Control "    2.76   88.8  2.45
 6 "I Control "    3.45   87.6  2.88
 7 "I Control "    4.14   86.9  3.22
 8 "I Control "    4.83   83.9  5.53
 9 "I Control "    5.52   83.1  5.55
10 "I Control "    6.21   81.9  6.24
```

I have 16 different values for the variable "Treatment". I would like to have a csv file that looks like this:

[image: TableinExcel]

As you can see from the picture, each value from the variable "Treatment" has 2 rows, one containing the values of the variable "mean" and the other containing the values from the variable "std". In the csv table each column would represent each different value from the variable "Pressure".

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks in advance for the time.

Comment: Possible to send partner to reeducation camp for sensible data organization?

Comment: No, I am afraid that he's using an old spreadsheet to do some analysis and I honestly do not know much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data wasn't easily copied and under-represented the variability of the treatments, so I made some random data:

```
set.seed(2)
dat <- data_frame(
  Treatment = rep(letters[1:2], each=4),
  Pressure = sample(100, size=8),
  mean = sample(100, size=8),
  std = sample(100, size=8)
)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Here's a way:

```
dat %>%
  gather(k, v, -Treatment) %>%
  group_by(Treatment, k) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ as.data.frame(t(.$v)))) %>%
  unnest()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Treatment k           V1    V2    V3    V4
#   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 a         Pressure    19    70    57    17
# 2 b         Pressure    91    90    13    78
# 3 a         mean        47    55    99    24
# 4 b         mean        74    18    39    80
# 5 a         std         98    23    44     8
# 6 b         std         64    37    79    14
```

This works well even if your treatments are not well-balanced:

```
dat <- dat[-8,]
dat %>%
  gather(k, v, -Treatment) %>%
  group_by(Treatment, k) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ as.data.frame(t(.$v)))) %>%
  unnest()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Treatment k           V1    V2    V3    V4
#   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 a         Pressure    19    70    57    17
# 2 b         Pressure    91    90    13    NA
# 3 a         mean        47    55    99    24
# 4 b         mean        74    18    39    NA
# 5 a         std         98    23    44     8
# 6 b         std         64    37    79    NA
```

From here, just append `%>% write.csv(path, na="")` or `%>% readr::write_csv(path, na="")`, so that the empty cells are not filled in excel.

Comment: Thank's for the help @r2evans.

Comment: You guys saved me a lot of time. I made use of the code you provided and both worked. I decided to stick with the second since in the first one (I guess) I had to write all the treatments after the parameter  `Label = 'I Control '`, perhaps a list? `Label = c('I control', 'II Control', etc...)`. I did not tried that though.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a matter of converting your data from the wide format into a long format and then into the desired wide format again.  There are a couple of possible solutions, in this case I used `gather` and `spread` from the tidyr package.

```
df<-structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "I Control ", class = "factor"), Pressure = c(0, 
        0.689, 1.38, 2.07, 2.76, 3.45, 4.14, 4.83, 5.52, 6.21), mean = c(97.2, 
        94.1, 90.9, 89.5, 88.8, 87.6, 86.9, 83.9, 83.1, 81.9), std = c(1.03, 
        1.35, 2.01, 2.2, 2.45, 2.88, 3.22, 5.53, 5.55, 6.24)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
        "Pressure", "mean", "std"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


library(tidyr)
long<-gather(df, variable, value, 3:4)
answer<-spread(long, Pressure, value)

write.csv(answer, "Answer.csv")
```

Of course if the pressure is different from treatment to treatment the final dataframe will be quite messy.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why my sample data didn't work well with your solution, but your last comment nails it: I found the messy solution. Great caveat.

Comment: @r2evans, agreed.  The completeness of the question determines the completeness of the solution.  Your solution does provide for a more general input.

Comment: The assumption that `$Pressure` has constant values is "kinda safe" in that one might infer that that is the controlled variable, but then again the design might have a *target* pressure (constant) but then measure *actual* (varying). \*shrug\*, I think both answers are good to have.

Comment: Actually you made it right. The variable "Pressure" has the same values for all the treatments. Thanks for the answer @Dave2e and the help.